# jquery asp.net get value from GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrongly.
My gridview looks like this:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                                    
                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hfamount" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("inst_amt") %>'/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("inst_amt") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="first_name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hffname" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("first_name") %>'/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and my jquery like this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $("[id*=GridView1] [id*=lnkDelete]").click(function () {
                  if (confirm("Do you want to delete this Customer?")) {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                      var amount = parseInt(row.find("[id*=hfamount]").val());
                      var name= row.find("[id*=hffname]").val();
```

Now the amount is correctly fetched but not the name...any idea why this is so?

thanks.

Comment: Is the parent of id="hffname" a hr tag ? Did you tried prevAll() ?

Comment: sorry not an expert in jquery - not sure what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just drop a button into the GV and wire up that button to do the delete.

And you can drop into the grid a standard button, or a link button (it don't matter).
However, Linkbutton is nice since we can include say a bootstrap glyphicon.

So, lets go with the LinkButton

So, say with with GV markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn ">
                   <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                   Delete
                   </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Ok, our code to load the grid could be:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels Order by HotelName ", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rst As New DataTable
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rst
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

and we now have this:

[image]

Ok, lets wire up the server side delete event - so we type in the markup OnClick, and intel-sense will give the option to create a event for the button

eg: choose create new event like this:

[image]

Ok, flip to code behind, and we wire up the delete event

```
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As LinkButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim PKID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim strSQL As String = "DELETE FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = " & PKID

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSql As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note how we used the DataKeys. DataKeys is REALLY nice, since it means the GV matintins the row PK, but we do NOT have to include the PK row in the GV markup. This not only eliminates the need for extra Eval("ID") as some hidden GV column, but it also enhances security - since we NEVER show, render, expose, or supply to the web UI the PK values - nd this also eliminates any kind of hacking of scripts or even trying to mess with database PK row id's.

Next up, we need to pop up the confirmation dialog. As we know, you can add to any plane jane asp .net button (or link buttion) a OnClientClick event. If that event returns true, then the button click occurs - if return false, then the server side button click does not fire/run the code behind.

So, the most simple setup could be this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                     OnClick="cmdDelete_Click" 
                     OnClientClick="return mydelprompt()"   >
                   <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                   Delete
                        
                   </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

            <script>
                function mydelprompt() {
                    return confirm ("Delete this hotel?")
                }
            </script>
```

and now if we hit delete button, we get this:

[image]

Now, the above is really quite much all you need here. However I find that the built-in "confirm" or alert() box of browsers are VERY ugly. (why they are not cleaned up, and made all nice and pretty is BEYOND me!!!!).

But, we can probably assume that we have jQuery, so I would suggest adding jQuery.UI, since then we can create VERY nice looking custom dialogs, and use that in place of say the "confirm()" from js - which looks quite amateurish .

So, assuming we introduce jQuery.UI? Well, then we can use this markup:

for client side, we now have this:

```
  OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"   >
```

And our js function (and our prompt div) looks like this:

```
        </asp:GridView>

            <div id="mydeltext" style="display:none">
                <h4><i>Delete this hotel</i></h4>
                <h4><i>(can't be undone)</i></h4>

            </div>

            <script>
                var mydelok = false
                function mydelprompt(btn) {

                    if (mydelok) {
                        mydelok = false
                        return true
                    }

                    myDialog = $("#mydeltext")
                    myDialog.dialog({
                        title: "Confrim Hotel Delete",
                        modal: true,
                        appendTo: "form",
                        position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom", of: btn },
                        buttons: {
                            Delete: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close')
                                mydelok = true
                                btn.click()
                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close')
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    return false                        
                }
            </script>
```

And now we get this:
[image]

So, all in all, we really don't need the js to "get" or have values from the row, since our GV code behind DOES in fact have the ability to get the PK row value.

But, I suppose, we STILL might want to get some value from that GV row - say we wanted to put the hotel name in that dialog - good idea, since user might bump their screen, or touch pad - you have a dialog prompt, but WHICH row?

Ok, in my GV, cells() don't get a id, but we could just replace the hotel with this markup:

```
          <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' >
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn"
                     OnClick="cmdDelete_Click" 
                     OnClientClick="return mydelprompt(this)"   >
                   <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                   Delete
                        
                   </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Ok, and we fancy up our "div" a bit like this:

```
           <div id="mydeltext" style="display:none">
                <h4><i>Delete this hotel (can't be undone)</i></h4>
                Hotel to delete:
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="txtHotelDel" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>

            </div>

            <script>
                var mydelok = false
                function mydelprompt(btn) {

                    if (mydelok) {
                        mydelok = false
                        return true
                    }
                    var txtHotel = btn.getAttribute("ID").replace("cmdDelete","txtHotel")

                    $("#txtHotelDel").text($('#' + txtHotel).text())

                    myDialog = $("#mydeltext")
                    myDialog.dialog({
                        title: "Confrim Hotel Delete",
                        modal: true,
                        width: '350',
                        appendTo: "form",
                        closeText: "",
                        position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window },
                        buttons: {
                            Delete: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close')
                                mydelok = true
                                btn.click()
                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog('close')
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    return false                        
                }
            </script>
```

Since we pass the button click (this), then we can just swap (repalce) cmdDelete with txtHotel, and we now have the hotel name.

The results are now this:

[image]

So the above shows how we could for example pull other values from the given row click in the client side code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer but that does not help - my question was a different one:

Now the amount is correctly fetched but not the name...any idea why this is so?

Comment: The last example js code does show how to get the value of the hotel name out of the given row click - I don't see the linkg button for delete in your markup (where is it???). If you don't have one, then drop in a stanard asp.net button, (or maybe a asp link button = either is fine). I then show how to get HotelName from that click. You can (should/have to) use the same approach.  I don't see in your markup the button in the grid and its OnClientClick event. If you dont have such a button, then add it - really that simple. We assume you drop into (add) a button to your grid for this to work